# python add string return weird character

Tags: python, string

this is a part of my source code that return not true

```
query = ""
for i in range(len(values)):
        if type(values.values()[i]) is str:            
            query += "'" + str(values.values()[i]) + "', "
        else:
            query += str(values.values()[i]) + ", "
```

when I use

```
values = {'Date': '2014-08-09 07:12:40', 'Ip': '127.0.0.1', 'MembershipID': 1}
```

query is

```
"\\\'2014-08-09 07:12:40\\\', \\\'127.0.0.1\\\', 1, "
```

instead of

```
"'2014-08-09 07:12:40', '127.0.0.1', 1, "
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to create SQL values? If so, *don't*; leave that to your database adapter and use SQL parameters.

Comment: you should iterate over `values.values()` directly, instead of this complicated structure: `for value in values.values():`

Comment: tried your code.It is correct and giving expected output.Where are you getting this weird output from? which python version or where are you executing it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you very much, i use python 2.7 and google app engine with pycharm. i found that problem in debug mode. Yes its for MySql query. i am new on python and did not know there is something like sqlparameter in C#.

Comment: @Mahyar: Use `%(Date)s` and `%(Ip)s` and `%(MembershipID)s` as placeholders in your SQL query, then use `cursor.execute(query, values)` to execute. The database will replace the `%(...)s` parameters with the values taken from the dictionary for you, quoting as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** try to quote SQL parameters yourself. Instead, leave this to the database adapter; it can do it more efficiently, always correctly and helps make database query parsing more efficient.

For MySQL you can use named parameters in the form of `%(name)s` and pass in your dictionary as the second argument to `cursor.execute()`:

```
query = '''\
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE
    date < %(Date)s AND 
    ip_address = %(Ip)s AND
    membership = %(MembershipId)s
'''
cursor.execute(query, values)
for row in cursor:
    # ...
```